# How to get the global health status actuator springboot 1.5.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

i'm using **SpringBoot v 1.5.3** in my application and i added actuators **health**, info and metrics, and they are working fine using the available endpoints.
I need to **get the global health status of my application**.

Here is my code:

```
package com.test.health.indicator;


import java.util.Collections;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.Info;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.InfoContributor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;

@Component
public class healthContributorToInfo implements InfoContributor {
     private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
    
    
    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        
        Health health = ((HealthIndicator) this.healthEndpoint).health();
        Status status = health.getStatus();

        
        builder.withDetail("Health Indicator",
                Collections.singletonMap("Global Satatus", Health.status(status.getCode())));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately my code return null exception because and i don't get the health status object.
Can someone know how to do that.
Thank you!

Comment: How do you expect `healthEndpoint` to be assigned a value?

Comment: Yes what i want to do is to get the status of the heath actuator, yes for your question i'm excepting to get this information.. but i'm not sure how to do that.. in this code bellow i got null exception wich mean i'm not getting what i want.

Answer (score 0):

`private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;` might be null? How is it set/injected in the component? I don't see any constructor that would set a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below line is giving a NPE since you have not injected a dependency of the HealthEndPoint.

```
    Health health = ((HealthIndicator) this.healthEndpoint).health();
```

Can you try autowiring or do a constructor injection for HealthEndPoint and see if that works.